# Who are some notable Sound Designers?

Tags: sound-design, contact, job

I wanted to call any sound designer who has had professional experience in the industry because I am studying to become a recording engineer/sound designer within a year. I haven't had much luck finding sound designer's contacts.

Comment: I'm sure if you hang around here you'll get to talk to them soon enough. What do you mean you "want to call" them? Are you looking for an internship?

Comment: I guess we're all confused by your motives.  If you're looking for an internship or job shadow, then you're barking up the wrong tree.  If you need to interview them for a school paper or something, start with email, but they may be more receptive. Don't cold call anyone.

Answer (score 10):

As expressed above, getting some of these folks on the phone is going to prove difficult - and possibly even detrimental to your future career. (If somebody cold-called me in the middle of a tight schedule I'd be less inclined to take time out to chat, plus I'd want to know how they got my number.) That being said, I've had a number of people contact me through reliable channels that have led to productive conversations, visits and even job offers.

Regarding notable sound designers: I think you'll find SSD to be a wealth of knowledge, not only in how people approach sound design but also as a who's-who in the business. Many of the contributors are well-established sound designers for film, television, games, etc. And of course there are the more well-known who have published interviews and Q&As all over the place: Ben Burtt, Gary Rydstrom, Harry Cohen, Christopher Boyes, Glenn Freemantle, Richard King, etc. Look up any of those names on [imdb.com](http://www.imdb.com/) if you're unsure of who they are.

Answer (score 3):

I can almost guarantee that cold-calling ANY sound designer out there, for any reason other than offering work, will get you a negative response.  Try email first (and, if you have trouble finding email contacts, you need to work on your Google-Fu), and, if they get back to you, ask if it's cool to call them.

But, to answer your question: Aaron Marks.  He wrote *The Complete Guide to Game Audio*, and I know from my own personal experience that he returns emails.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to the boards.  This place'll do you more good than a single phone call with a working sound designer any day.

Answer (score 1):

+1, this place is a wealth of knowledge

Comment: But the question itself is misleading at best, with a high possibility of being very annoying.

Comment: well the purpose of the call would just be for advice, one on one talk, establish network. I guess I can do that here as well. I wouldn't call it cold calling just merely a friendly call, i aint promoting or asking for jobs. I've called many recording engineers and some have been flattered that someone random would be looking up to them for advice.

Answer (score 1):

And realize that by nature all sound designers are a bit off our rocker.  What would drive someone normal to contrive sounds in unintended ways to fit with a video picture. :)

Plus, we're all a bit socially awkward so email is your best bet.  Here is my email: Matthew@matthewfreed.com

Feel free to ask me any questions you may have.  I've been doing this full time for 12 years.  Sound design and production sound mixing is all I do for a living.

Comment: Plus working in a dark room by themselves all day, every day??

Answer (score 1):

Tristan,

My first job in sound came by me cold calling a small studio in NYC and offering to take the owner (and sole employee) out to lunch to pick his brain about the tools of the trade.  I offered to answer phones and do small tasks during that day in exchange for getting time on the equipment at night.  Eventually he hired me at a VERY low rate, but it led to credits which led to more work.  That was 1995 or so.

People like it if you show interest in their work, especially if a free lunch is included.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ask away Tristan I'm sure there's tons of people here who could quickly list their years experience and type of area of sound design they work in when posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys for the warm welcome.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that in many cases cold calling can be detrimental, I got my first full time gig at a local mom and pop studio by cold calling and a bit of luck. It just so happened that the day before I called, another person had unexpectedly quit and they needed to replace them immediately. I was editing that afternoon.

Always leave a little room for serendipity.